# How to make linked(dynamic?) select fields in oracle jet?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, oracle-jet

Im very new to JS and OJET. I'm using oracle jet to create a form. I need to create two select fields, the firts displays a client's name and the next one must change is values with the selected client's team members.

I have a JSON File with this format:

```
{
"clients": [
    {
        "id": "C01",
        "name": "Client 1",
        "manager": "Manager 1",
        "team": [
            {
               "id": "C1MEM1",
               "name": "member 1"
            },
            {
                "id": "C1MEM2",
                "name": "member 2"
            },
            {
                "id": "C1MEM3",
                "name": "member 3"
            },
            {
                "id": "C1MEM4",
                "name": "Member 4"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "C02",
        "name": "Client 2",
        "manager": "Manager 2",
        "team": [
            {
               "id": "C2MEM1",
               "name": "member 1"
            },
            {
                "id": "C2MEM2",
                "name": "member 2"
            },
            {
                "id": "C2MEM3",
                "name": "member 3"
            },
            {
                "id": "C2MEM4",
                "name": "member 4"
            }
        ]
    }
```

I managed to create a select field with the clients name:

```
self.clientsListVal = ko.observableArray(['C01']);
  self.clientsList = ko.observableArray();
  $.getJSON("http://localhost:8000/js/json/clients.json").
    then(function(data){
      $.each(data["clients"],function(){
        self.clientsList.push({
          value: this.id,
          label: this.name
        });
      });
    });
```

Then I tried to get the next select fields this way, but it doesn't work :( :

```
self.memberList = ko.observableArray();

$.getJSON("http://localhost:8000/js/json/clients.json").
then(function(data){
    $.each(data["clients"],function(){
        if (this.id === self.clientsListVal ) {
            $.each(this["team"], function(){
                self.memberList.push({
                    value: this.id,
                    label: this.name
                });
            });
        }
    });
});
```

This is the HTML im using:

```
    <div class="oj-applayout-content">
<div role="main" class="oj-hybrid-applayout-content">
  <div class="oj-hybrid-padding">
    <h3>Dashboard Content Area</h3>
    <div>
        <label for="clients">Clients</label>
        <select id="clients"
        data-bind="ojComponent:
        {component: 'ojSelect',
        options: clientsList,
        value: clientsListVal,
        rootAttributes: {style:'max-width:20em'}}">
        </select>


        <label for="select-value">Current selected value is</label>
        <span id="select-value" data-bind="text: clientsListVal"></span>

        <label for="members">Members</label>
        <select id="members"
        data-bind="ojComponent: {component: 'ojSelect',
        options: memberList,
        value: memberListVal,
        rootAttributes: {style:'max-width:20em'}}">
        </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help or hint? thank you!.

EDIT:
I think the problem is that **self.clientsListVal** is returning a function not the current selected value. I added console.log(self.clientsListVal) to the view model to see the current value.

If I change **self.clientsListVal** for a string:

```
if(this.id === 'C01'){}
```

I get the members of the client "C01".

I tried changing  **self.clientsListVal** to **$('#clients').val()**, this is the id of the select input and i get undefined in the console.log.

How can I get the select field string value inside the viewmodel?

Comment: Can you provide more information about what's not working? Perhaps an error message you're getting?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I think the problem is that self.clientsListVal is returning a function not the current selected value. If I change **self.clientsListVal** for a string: **if(this.id === 'C01')** I get the members of the client "C01".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Knockout, observables are functions -- so when you ask for the observable directly, like `self.clientsListVal`, you get the function definition. To get the underlying value, call the observable like a function: `self.clientsListVal()`.

So your test becomes `if (this.id === self.clientsListVal() ) {`

Now you have another problem -- the observable holds an array, not an ID. The array may have a single ID element in it, but you have to reach into the array to get it.

Since you didn't show us how a value gets into `clientsListVal`, it's hard to say what you need to do. Is it bound to an input field where the user specifies a value? Is it populated from a data call? either way, do you ever need to have more than one ID in `clientsListVal`? If you only need to hold one ID at a time, change `clientsListVal` from an `observableArray` to a simple `observable` and your test will work.

If `clientsListVal` can hold multiple values, you'll need to loop over them. There are various ways to do this. You can get the underlying array by assigning the value of the observableArray to a variable: `var clients = clientsListVal()`. `clients` now holds the array, and you can use jQuery's `$.each`, the native `Array.each`, or some other way to loop over or map the array. Or you can use Knockout's [built-in array utilities](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/utility-functions-in-knockoutjs.html), like `arrayForEach`

if you don't want to change to a regular observable but expect the array to only have a single element, you can get at it like `clientsListVal()[0]` -- that's the 0th (first) element of the array. Watch out for empty arrays, tho.

Comment: Hay Val thank you for your help! `clientsListVal` gets its value from a select field. I'm going to include the html in my question. I manage to make the test work by changing `clientListVal` to a simple `observable` since it only holds a value. I was following an example in the oracle jet cookbook that's why I was using an `observableArray`.

Comment: In the [cookbook example](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet/jetCookbook.html?component=select&demo=optionsBinding) you first assign the selected value inside a `observableArray`, then you generate the select input from an array and the user can choose  the new value.

Comment: I think the Oracle cookbook example uses an observableArray to hold the selected value so it can support multi-select inputs. When you use it with a regular menu control you can only select a single value, and so you can store that in a plain observable. In the Oracle example you linked, I changed `this.selectVal = ko.observableArray(['Chrome']);` to `this.selectVal = ko.observable('Chrome');` and the example worked fine. You should be safe using an observable.